# AttributeError: 'dataAcquisition' object has no attribute 'gpioButton'

Tags: python, pyqt4, qt-designer, attributeerror, pyuic

I'm trying to connect a push-button on my main window to open a new widget when I click it. But each time I run the program I get this error:

> AttributeError: 'dataAcquisition' object has no attribute 'gpioButton'

I will be grateful if someone can help.

Here's my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow
from gpiodialog import Ui_GPIODialog
import sys

class gpioDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_GPIODialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        flags = QtCore.Qt.Drawer | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWidowFlags(flags)
        self.ui = Ui_GPIODialog
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.gpioOKButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptOKButtonClicked)
    def acceptOKButtonClicked(self):
        self.close()        


class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.gpioButton.clicked.connect(self.gpioButton_clicked)
        self.popGPIO = gpioDialog()

    def gpioButton_clicked(self):
        self.popGPIO.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = dataAcquisition()
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

mainwindow.py code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'mainwindow.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Oct 18 02:57:57 2016
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(700, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(700, 600))
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        self.gpioButton = QtGui.QToolButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.gpioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 80, 181, 61))
        self.gpioButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gpioButton"))
        self.procButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.procButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 180, 181, 61))
        self.procButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("procButton"))
        self.startButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.startButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.startButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 360, 131, 51))
        self.startButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("startButton"))
        self.stopButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.stopButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 360, 131, 51))
        self.stopButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("stopButton"))
        self.plotButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.plotButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 460, 181, 61))
        self.plotButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("plotButton"))
        self.columnView = QtGui.QColumnView(self.centralwidget)
        self.columnView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 50, 341, 251))
        self.columnView.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("columnView"))
        self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 20, 221, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(15)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
        self.saveButton = QtGui.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.saveButton.setEnabled(True)
        self.saveButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 420, 211, 31))
        self.saveButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("saveButton"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 700, 27))
        self.menubar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menubar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None))
        self.gpioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "GPIO Number of inputs", None))
        self.procButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Processing", None))
        self.startButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Acquiring", None))
        self.stopButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Stop Acquiring", None))
        self.plotButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Start Live Plot", None))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Data Acquisition System", None))
        self.saveButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Save this session\'s data", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

gpiodialog.py code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'gpiodialog.ui'
#
# Created: Tue Oct 18 03:11:51 2016
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.2
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_GPIODialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, GPIODialog):
        GPIODialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("GPIODialog"))
        GPIODialog.resize(400, 300)
        self.gpioOKButton = QtGui.QPushButton(GPIODialog)
        self.gpioOKButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 240, 101, 31))
        self.gpioOKButton.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gpioOKButton"))
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel(GPIODialog)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 20, 191, 21))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(13)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))

        self.retranslateUi(GPIODialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(GPIODialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, GPIODialog):
        GPIODialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("GPIODialog", "Dialog", None))
        self.gpioOKButton.setText(_translate("GPIODialog", "OK", None))
        self.label.setText(_translate("GPIODialog", "Choose GPIO input bins", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GPIODialog = QtGui.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_GPIODialog()
    ui.setupUi(GPIODialog)
    GPIODialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The error is very explicit. In your dataAcquisition class, there is no gpioButton attribute but you call it here: self.gpioButton.clicked.connect(self.gpioButton_clicked)

Comment: The gpioButton is in mainwindow.py file, which was imported in the beginning of the code and called it here:

class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a separate namespace for the ui, so you would need to access the button like this:

```
    self.ui.gpioButton.clicked.connect(self.gpioButton_clicked)
```

However, if you'd prefer to have all the widgets as attributes of the window, do this:

```
class gpioDialog(QtGui.QDialog, Ui_GPIODialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(gpioDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        flags = QtCore.Qt.Drawer | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint
        self.setWindowFlags(flags)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.gpioOKButton.clicked.connect(self.acceptOKButtonClicked)


class dataAcquisition(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(dataAcquisition, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.gpioButton.clicked.connect(self.gpioButton_clicked)
        self.popGPIO = gpioDialog()
```

Comment: That's really great! I tried the second code and now it is working!!
Thank you so much @ekhumoro